# Django writing a custom decorator

Tags: python, django

I am building a forum. When processing urls there is a board id and a board name. The name is for readability and the id is what fetches the board. This means if the name is wrong or has changed I want to redirect the user to the proper url. Some searching has led me to decorators but I cannot find any resource teaching me how to use them.

```
# urls.py
...
url(r'^boards/(?P<board_id>\d+)/(?P<board_name>[^/]+)/$', views.board, name='board'),
...

# views.py
@redirect_if_wrong_boardname
def board(request, board_id, board_name):
    ...
    return render(request, 'forums/board.html', {'board': board})
```

How would I implement the following logic in a decorator?

```
board = Board.objects.all().get(pk=pk)
    if (board.name != name):
        return redirect(request.get_full_path().replace(name, board.name, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

After some guesswork, help from my brother and stumbling across some lucky posts I've figured it out:

```
# views.py
def redirect_if_wrong_boardname(func):
    def wrapper(request, board_id, board_name):
        try:
            board = Board.objects.get(pk=board_id)
            if (board.name != board_name):
                return redirect('/boards/' + board.pk + '/' + board.name)
            else:
                return func(request, board_id, board_name)
        except:
            return Http404('Board not found')
    return wrapper

@redirect_if_wrong_boardname
def board(request, board_id, board_name):
    ...
    return render(request, 'forums/board.html', {'board': board})
```

Comment: Why is a decorator useful here?  Your implementation is highly coupled to the Board model and to that particular url. Decorators are more often used to add behavior reusable interchangeably to varying functions. You're totally free to do what you want but imho that's an unusual way to use a decorator, unless it's a prototype.  Nothing worong with your code, it would just work as well in the view function.

Comment: Yep, thats what this is: an example. I'm planning on using a variant of this on many views that take a board_name parameter.

Comment: experiment away!  django is extremely flexible pushed out of its boundaries.